# Is there a way todo a Group By and Sum without explicitly typing out every field name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have some data frames which are pretty wide; 37 to 300+ fields.  Virtually all fields consist of floats and numerics.  I want to do a Group By and Sum on all these fields without manually typing out each filed name.  Is that possible?

Here are my `df.columns` results:

```
Index(['IDRSSD', 'RCON5562', 'RCON5563', 'RCON5564', 'RCON5565', 'RCON5566',
       'RCON5567', 'RCON5568', 'RCON5569', 'RCON5570', 'RCON5571', 'RCON5572',
       'RCON5573', 'RCON5574', 'RCON5575', 'RCON5576', 'RCON5577', 'RCON5578',
       'RCON5579', 'RCON5580', 'RCON5581', 'RCON5582', 'RCON5583', 'RCON5584',
       'RCON5585', 'RCON5586', 'RCON5587', 'RCON5588', 'RCON5589', 'RCON6860',
       'RCON6999', 'Unnamed_1', 'Unnamed_31', 'file'],
      dtype='object')
```

Also, here is the code that I am testing.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['qyear'])
grouped_and_summed = grouped_df.sum()
grouped_and_summed = grouped_and_summed.reset_index().T
```

That gives me 4 rows and 73 columns, for the quarter-end values in my data set.  I would expect 33 rows, for the 33 fields, and 73 columns.  I believe something is missing from the `grouped_df.sum()`

So, I tried the code below, hoping to grab the column names dynamically.

```
df_list = df.columns.values.tolist()
df = df.groupby(df_list)
grouped_df = df.groupby(['qyear'])
grouped_and_summed = grouped_df.sum()
grouped_and_summed = grouped_and_summed.reset_index().T
```

When I run that code, I get this error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'groupby'`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing `groupby` on the field named 'file' and everything worked out just fine.

```
grouped_and_summed = df_append.groupby(['qyear']).sum()
```